# Second Order Linear Differential Equations with Constant Coefficients Containing Trigonometric Functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm having trouble applying the method of undetermined coefficients, as explained in Apostol's *Calculus*, to second order linear differential equations with constant coefficients containing trigonometric functions. For second-order linear differential equations with constant coefficients of the form $y'' + ay' + by = p(x)e^{mx}$, where $p$ is a polynomial, we assume that $y = u(x)e^{mx}$ for some function $u$ to arrive at a polynomial in $u$, which is easily solved. However, this method isn't working as expected when applied to equations of the form $y'' + ay' + by = p(x)e^{mx}\sin\alpha x$ or $y'' + ay' + by = p(x) e^{mx} \cos\alpha x$. I begin by assuming that $y = e^{mx}u(x)\sin\alpha x$ for some function $u$. Differentiating twice, we obtain an equation of the form
$$e^{mx}\sin\alpha x (\phi_1 u'' + \phi_2 u' + \phi_3 u + \phi_4) + e^{mx}\cos \alpha x (\psi_1 u'' + \psi_2 u' + \psi_3 u + \psi_4) = p(x)e^{mx}\sin \alpha x$$
where $\phi_i$ and $\psi_i$ depend only on $a$, $b$, $m$ and $\alpha$ for $1 \leq i \leq 4$. Dividing by $e^{mx}\sin\alpha x$ gives rise to a system of differential equations equations of the form
$$\phi_1 u'' + \phi_2 u' + \phi_3 u + \phi_4 = p(x) \\
\cot \alpha x (\psi_1 u'' + \psi_2 u' + \psi_3 u + \psi_4) = 0$$
A similar situation arises when I assume that $y = e^{mx}(u(x)\sin\alpha x + v(x) \cos \alpha x)$ for some functions $u$ and $v$, or when $\sin \alpha x$ is replaced by $\cos \alpha x$. I have tried dividing through by $\cot \alpha x$ in the second equation and solving the resultant system, but my answers in example problems aren't agreeing with those given in the text. In addition, my method leads to quite complex formulas. This leads me to believe that I'm applying the method of undetermined coefficients incorrectly. Thus, I'm looking for some help applying this method to equations of the indicated type, preferably using only tools and techniques developed by Apostol through Section 8.16 of *Calculus* (Vol. I).

**Edit:** A particular example is $y'' - 3y' = 2e^{2x}\sin x$. Letting $y = ue^{2x}\sin x$ for some function $u$, I obtain $e^{2x}\sin x (u'' - 2u) + e^{2x}\cos x(u'' + 3u' + 3u) = 2e^{2x}\sin x$. This gives rise to the pair of equations $u'' - 2u = 2$ and $\cot x (u'' + 3u' + 3u) = 0$. Proceeding from this point, I obtain an incorrect solution (although I admit, my problem could be simple algebra).

Comment: Is there any certain ODE in your mind?

Comment: Babak S., I assume that I'm supposed to apply this method to exercises like $y'' + y = e^{2x}\cos 3x$ or $y'' - 3y' = 2e^{2x}\sin x$. But in the question, I'm looking for a more systematic way to solve the generic equation, so that I can solve particular examples later and understand how the method is applied.

Comment: You might consider writing $\sin$ and $\cos$ as expontials *via* the Euler formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$.

Comment: Could you post a precise example ? By the way, it seems that there is a typo in your first equation (is b' standing for b y ?)

Comment: Claude, Babak S.: I added an example, and an outline of my attempt at solving it along the indicated lines.

Comment: @portin.daniel. I think I miss a point : where is the "y" gone. If there is no "y" in your ODE, the problem is quite different and what Babak S. wrote is exwactly what you need. Please clarify for the old stupid idiot I feel to be !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the method called undetermined coefficients, I think we should consider different cases. These cases are as follows. Let you are facing $$a_ny^{(n)}+\cdots a_0y=Q(x),~~~a_n\neq 0, ~~Q(x)\not\equiv 0~(x\in I)$$ You may know that for finding the particular solution $y_p(x)$, using this method, we have to compare the terms of $Q(x)$ and the terms in $y_c(x)$ such that all terms are independent on interval $I$. Now we can consider some cases which one of these are as follows:

1. None of the terms in $Q(x)$ is the same as any term in $y_c(x)$. In this case, you can consider $y_p$ as a linear combination of the terms in $Q(x)$ and all its linearly independent derivatives.

For example, in your latest sample, the axillary equation is $m^2-3m=0$ and so $$y_c(x)=C_1+C_2e^{3x}$$ There is no term in $y_c$ similar to term in $\sin x e^{2x}$ so we set $y_p=A\sin x e^{2x}+B\cos  x e^{2x}$ for proper values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Well done, @Babak! +1

Comment: You are a very good teacher

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see where I was going wrong. I wasn't applying the method of undetermined coefficients correctly. Letting $y = e^{mx}(u(x)\cos\alpha x + v(x)\sin\alpha x)$ and correctly guessing $u$ and $v$ solved the problem (as in your example).

Comment: @portin.daniel: I am glad I could give you a hand. :)